# substr() to EOL?

Tags: php, substr, eol

How can I grab the entire contents of a line? I have a suspicion `substr()` is not the answer.

```
Authors: Mr. Foo, Mr. Bar
Date: Jan 1, 1970
etc...
```

In my `$file_text` string I have something similar to above. I'm looking for something like this:

```
$author_line = substr($file_text, 0, EOL);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the file contents with [`file()`](http://php.net/file) automatically cuts it up into lines for you, if it helps.

Otherwise, try [`strstr($file_text,PHP_EOL,true)`](http://php.net/strstr)

Comment: Good point, file will move each line into a new element within the returned array.

Answer (score 2):

Grab each line with this:

```
$eachLine = explode( PHP_EOL, $file_text );
```

Then your normal substring will just grab everything. If it's all separated by colons like in your example, you could then explode to extract an key => value array of all the data in your string

```
// Grab each Line
$eachLine = explode( PHP_EOL, $file_text );
$data= array();

foreach($eachLine as $line) {

    $line = explode($line, ':');

    $data[trim($line[0])] = trim($line[1]);

}
```

This will give you a key => value array for all of the data in `$data`.

Comment: You read my mind with where I was going!! I accepted the other answer as correct because it answered the question I actually asked.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$lines = explode( PHP_EOL, $line_text );
```

Then loop over each line:

```
foreach( $lines as $line ) 
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: You're using the arguments in reverse order.

Comment: You will also need to double quote `\n` or it won't be treated as a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Get the first line (Replace end-of-line delimiter with your choice):

```
$author_line = strtok($file_text, "\n");
```

Alternative:

```
list($author_line) = explode("\n", $file_text, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$author_line = substr($file_text, 0, strpos("\n"));
```

That will grab everything on the first line not including the end of line.  You'll have to take into consideration \r\n on Windows vs. \n on Unix.

More properly coded as:

```
$author_line = substr($file_text, 0, strpos(PHP_EOL));
```

Comment: Thats what `PHP_EOL` is for :)

Comment: Thanks .. I should have used that in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

```
$author_line = explode("\n", $file_text );
```